# IOS searchBar - Getting rid of the white space below

Tags: ios, uitableview, searchbar

I have a view which has two containers: Top_Container and Bottom_Container.
Each Container points to a VC with a TableView.

The Bottom_Container points to a TableView with a searchBar on top.

Whenever the searchBar gets activated in the TableView a white space appears below the searchBar between the searchBar and the greyed zone corresponding to the serachBarTableView (which superposes the TableView).

I have been trying with no success to get rid of this white space with no success.

Anybody has an idea how to customize:
- the white space which appears below the searchBar ?
- the greyed zone (searchBar TableView ?) on top of the TableView which appears whenever the searchBar gets active ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an image of what your want to get rid of ?

Comment: Please mention version of iOS and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
CGRect rect = self.searchBar.frame;
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height-2,rect.size.width, 2)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.searchBar addSubview:lineView];
```

It is fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case it was caused by opaque `NavigationBar`. When I set NavigationBar to translucent, then the underlaying `UITableView` is correctly aligned to the active `UISearchBar`. (note: I'm using `UISearchDisplayController` in my view controller)

In your case maybe you can move (and animate) the underlaying table view in `UISearchDisplayDelegate`'s methods `willBeginSearch` and `willEndSearch`. If you are using `UISearchBar` only, then you need to subclass it and override `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` methods and implement the "table view moving" code there.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem in my own code. For me, the issue was caused by 2 lines of code.

`self.viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` 
`self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

After removing both these lines, everything worked as expected.